# mfc assert failed asserted fail at wincore.cpp line 1846

Tags: mfc

I have domodal issue by using cpropertysheet object.domodal in dlg object.
the specific assertion failed message is as follow
ASSERT(pMessageMap != (*pMessageMap->pfnGetBaseMap)());
Is there anyone expericing the same problem?

expect to pop up the sheet doing other operation the code is following

```
 IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(msheet, CPropertySheet)
    #if 1
    msheet::msheet(UINT nIDCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage)
        :CPropertySheet(nIDCaption, pParentWnd, iSelectPage)
    {
        //CAdminDebug AdminDebugDlg;
        //this->AddPage(&AdminDebugDlg);
        AddPage(&AdminDebugDlg);
    }
    #endif
    
    msheet::msheet(LPCTSTR pszCaption,CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage)
        :CPropertySheet(pszCaption, pParentWnd, iSelectPage)
    {
        //CAdminDebug AdminDebugDlg;
        //this->AddPage(&AdminDebugDlg);
        AddPage(&AdminDebugDlg);
    }
    msheet::~msheet()
    {
    }
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(msheet, msheet)
        //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyPropertySheet)
            // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove mapping macros here.
        //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
        ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, &msheet::OnCancel)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()
    #if 1
    BOOL msheet::OnInitDialog(void)
    {
        BOOL bResult = CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();
    #if 0 
        CWnd *pWnd = GetDlgItem (IDOK);
        pWnd->ShowWindow (FALSE);
        //pWnd = GetDlgItem (IDHELP);
        //pWnd->ShowWindow (FALSE);
    #endif
    #if 0
        this->GetDlgItem(IDOK)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    #endif
    #if 1
        CWnd *pWnd = GetDlgItem (IDOK);
        if(pWnd && pWnd->GetSafeHwnd())
        pWnd->ShowWindow (FALSE);
    #endif
        return bResult;
    }
    #endif
    void msheet::OnCancel()
    {
         int kk=1;
         msheet::OnClose();
         
    }
    void CAXToolDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
    {
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        msheet msheet(_T("hello"), NULL,0);
        msheet.DoModal();
    }
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAXToolDlg, CDialog)
        ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CAXToolDlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: You probably messed up something related to some message map. Without seeing some relevant parts of your code we cannot tell you more.

Comment: Also a stack trace would be helpful

Comment: @Jabberwocky actually code is simple. I want to use button in object CAXToolDlg to pop up the msheet. I paste the entire msheet class. Due to the length of CAXToolDlg, I only paste the related code and message map parts. Still cannot figure out what is going on in the message map.

Comment: Assuming that *"AX"* is a hint that there's an ActiveX control on the dialog, you probably need to set up an [event map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/event-maps).